# Eclipse: com.google.maps.android.utils.demo linking fails

Tags: eclipse, adt

I have been strugling with integration of google maps utiliy

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering.

I use ADT (Eclipse) and is able to compile and 'almost' launch it as an Android application. But crashes during startup.

This is what I get from LogCat

```
02-22 09:49:05.386: I/dalvikvm(13953): Failed resolving Lcom/google/maps/android/utils/demo/CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity; interface 2305 'Lcom/google/maps/android/clustering/ClusterManager$OnClusterClickListener;'
02-22 09:49:05.386: W/dalvikvm(13953): Link of class 'Lcom/google/maps/android/utils/demo/CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity;' failed
02-22 09:49:05.386: E/dalvikvm(13953): Could not find class 'com.google.maps.android.utils.demo.CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity', referenced from method com.google.maps.android.utils.demo.MainActivity.onCreate
02-22 09:49:05.386: W/dalvikvm(13953): VFY: unable to resolve const-class 2324 (Lcom/google/maps/android/utils/demo/CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity;) in Lcom/google/maps/android/utils/demo/MainActivity;
02-22 09:49:05.386: D/dalvikvm(13953): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1c at 0x001d
02-22 09:49:05.486: D/AndroidRuntime(13953): Shutting down VM
02-22 09:49:05.486: W/dalvikvm(13953): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41926898)
02-22 09:49:05.486: E/AndroidRuntime(13953): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-22 09:49:05.486: E/AndroidRuntime(13953): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.maps.android.utils.demo.CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity
02-22 09:49:05.486: E/AndroidRuntime(13953):    at com.google.maps.android.utils.demo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:21)
```

Anybody have experienced similar problem?

Regards OFK

Comment: Same problem here.  Ever solve this?

Comment: I am encountering this problem. The error I'm getting is could not find (or link) CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity although there are no compiler or lint errors and this class is in the package. Very odd. I find it curious that not more people are seeing this.

Comment: Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22840952/couldnt-run-google-maps-android-api-utility-demo/23002240#23002240 for the solution.