# couldn't run Google Maps Android API Utility Demo

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-utils

i'm having problems to run the Google Maps Android API Utility Demo, it shows this error:

```
04-03 16:32:37.397: E/dalvikvm(2592): Could not find class 'com.google.maps.android.utils.demo.ClusteringDemoActivity', referenced from method com.google.maps.android.utils.demo.MainActivity.onCreate
    04-03 16:32:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2592): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    04-03 16:32:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2592): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.maps.android.utils.demo.ClusteringDemoActivity
    04-03 16:32:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2592):     at com.google.maps.android.utils.demo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
    04-03 16:32:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2592):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5163)
    04-03 16:32:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2592):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
    04-03 16:32:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2061)
    04-03 16:32:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2122)
    04-03 16:32:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
    04-03 16:32:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2592):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1228)
    04-03 16:32:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2592):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    04-03 16:32:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2592):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    04-03 16:32:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2592):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4895)
    04-03 16:32:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2592):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    04-03 16:32:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2592):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    04-03 16:32:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2592):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:994)
    04-03 16:32:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2592):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:761)
    04-03 16:32:37.452: E/AndroidRuntime(2592):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

although i followed the steps shown in the installation demo, and the class **ClusteringDemoActivity** exists in the package.

Comment: post the code you tried

Comment: i imported the project demo from here : https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils

Answer (score 7):

I solved this by adding the GoogleMapsUtil as a library to the demo project.

If you are following the setup guide at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/setup at the step *Reference the utility library from the utility demo app* do the following instead:

1. Right click on your demo project (MainActivity) and choose Properties.
2. Click the Android tab.
3. Under the Library section click Add and select the maps util project (called library)

Comment: I was encountering this problem with CustomMarkerClusteringDemoActivity. Your solution addressed this as well. Thanks!!

Comment: This also solve other errors like: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
com.google.maps.android.heatmaps.HeatmapTileProvider$Builder (I put it here just in case other used GoogleMapsUtil directly as happened to me)

Answer (score 1):

The docs tell you to use:

```
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
```

Using this will give the error.  You must use android-maps-utils:0.3+

```
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.3+'
```

This will get rid of the error.

Comment: You'll notice that the library you import is also using android-maps-utils:0.3+, which is why it works